# Can't connect to discord bot because asynchronous error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to set up a bot in Python that is able to post in a Discord channel when the script is executed. I have set up the bot already and added it to the server but my Python script is raising errors and I'm not able to solve it.

I've already set up a different bot but that leads to the same result. Can someone help?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with this code:

```
## BOT

# IMPORT DISCORD.PY. ALLOWS ACCESS TO DISCORD'S API.
import discord

# GETS THE CLIENT OBJECT FROM DISCORD.PY. CLIENT IS SYNONYMOUS WITH BOT.
bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

# EVENT LISTENER FOR WHEN THE BOT HAS SWITCHED FROM OFFLINE TO ONLINE.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # CREATES A COUNTER TO KEEP TRACK OF HOW MANY GUILDS / SERVERS THE BOT IS CONNECTED TO.
    guild_count = 0

    # LOOPS THROUGH ALL THE GUILD / SERVERS THAT THE BOT IS ASSOCIATED WITH.
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        # PRINT THE SERVER'S ID AND NAME.
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")

        # INCREMENTS THE GUILD COUNTER.
        guild_count = guild_count + 1

        # PRINTS HOW MANY GUILDS / SERVERS THE BOT IS IN.
    print("SampleDiscordBot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")

# EXECUTES THE BOT WITH THE SPECIFIED TOKEN
bot.run('token')
```

Error

[image: Error message]

Eventually I want to have full control of the bot. So I can enter in Python say 'Hello' and it posts 'Hello' to the channel etc.

Comment: You can't do that from inside Jupyter.  You'll have to do it from a command line.

Comment: Could you explain how I can run that from the command line? Or do I need to use a different tool such as Visual Code?

Comment: VSCode would be another good alternative.  When it runs a script, it runs it by itself, but whe Jupyter runs a script, it's as a part of Jupyter -- like calling a function from inside of Jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your code inside a file (for example, let's call it `bot.py`) and run the code via an IDE or the command line.

To run via the command line, go to the folder where your script is and execute `py3 bot.py` if you're on windows, or `python3 bot.py` if you're on macOS or Linux.